# Why isn't the edit button calling my custom dataProvider?

Tags: react-admin

When I look at the network URL called in my developer console in chrome, I can see that the ${query} is not being appended after I press the edit button.

```
// from App.js
  <Admin dataProvider={sawyerDataProvider}>
       <Resource name="audits" list={AuditList} edit={EditGuesser} show={PostShow} create={PostCreate}/>
       
    </Admin>
);

//from sawyerDataProvider
    getOne: (resource, params) =>
        
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}?${query}`).then(({ json }) => ({
            data: json,
        })),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks to me like I thought the Edit button called the getOne function but I believe it actually calls the updateMany function.  When I added my query append to the updateMany function it works as expected.

```
updateMany: (resource, params) => {
        const query = {
            filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids}),
        };
        return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}?${query}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }));
    },
```